# SQL - select distinct from one column based on value from another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to run a SQL query that **counts** the **distinct** values from one column based on the value of another column being equal to X.

So for the below, I want to count the distinct values of the "value" column where the "field_number" column is equal to 2.

The result should return "2" (Australia and New Zealand)

[image]

Comment: Can you please give rough data and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(distinct value)
from your_table
where field_number = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query

```
select count(distinct value) from my_table where field_number = 2;
```

Check here [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/121fe/2)